# Regex: Allow blanks with digits

Tags: regex

Have this reg ex:

```
^((abc|def)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49[@\w.]+(,|$)|(abc|def)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)[@\w.]+(,|$))+$
```

How do I update to allow blank space? ie

```
abc: +49891111122222@url.com
abc: +4989 11111 22222@url.com
```

Both are valid

Answer (score 1):

At least, just add space in your character class:

```
^((abc|def)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49[@\w.\s]+.......
#                             here __^^
```

Comment: Technically, `\s` is any whitespace character. Keep this in mind if you only want the space character.